# How can I Select Specific Elements in a Column from Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, time-series, 2d

I converted a text file to pandas DF with 3 Columns (Time, range, Power). For each time (hour), I want to select all second elements in the corresponding power column (matches the second range - 217m) so that I could a Power (dB) vs time (hours) plot. Time starts at 10:00 UTC to 00:00 UTC

How I extracted and converted file into Dataframe

```
data = []

is_timestep_row = True


# Loop to iterate over all rows in the file
# we will perform different actions based on 
# the contents of a given file
irange = 0

for row in filedata:
    
    # 1. Check to see if the row is a header row
    if is_header_row(row,station_name='ctd'):
        
            
        # Ignore rows with station information        
        if "ctd" in row:
            pass
        
        # First header row contains timestamp info
        elif row[0] == "0":
            timestamp = get_timestamp(row)
            irange = 0
        
        # Second header row contains range info
        else:
            ranges = get_ranges(row)
            irange = 0
            
    # 2. If not header row, then row contains data
    else:
        
        # Get the ranges for gates
        rangeX = ranges[irange]

        # Read the Power data, which is the third item
        # in each data row
        PWR = get_data(row)
        
        # Create a single data point for each row which
        # contains timestamp, range, and SNR
        data_point = [timestamp, rangeX, PWR]
        
        # Save the data to the list
        data.append(data_point)
        
        irange += 1
        
# When iteration has completed, store data
# as a pandas dataframe
#pd.set_option('display.max_row',None)
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['time','range(m)','power (dB)'])
# data = np.array(data)
```

An output of the data frame structure.

| idx | time | range(m) | power(dB) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 157 | 45.052 |
| 1 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 217 | 46.612 |
| 2 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 277 | 44.732 |
| 3 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 337 | 47.922 |
| 4 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 397 | 47.532 |
| 5 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 457 | 41.732 |
| 6 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 517 | 39.692 |
| 7 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 577 | 38.142 |
| 8 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 637 | 40.302 |
| 9 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 697 | 42.352 |
| 10 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 757 | 43.932 |
| 11 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 817 | 41.412 |
| 12 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 877 | 40.362 |
| 13 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 937 | 40.112 |
| 14 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 997 | 41.882 |
| 15 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1057 | 42.812 |
| 16 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1117 | 42.752 |
| 17 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1177 | 36.272 |
| 18 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1237 | 27.382 |
| 19 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1297 | 24.842 |
| 20 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1357 | 25.672 |
| 21 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1417 | 24.842 |
| 22 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1477 | 22.912 |
| 23 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1537 | 24.672 |
| 24 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1597 | 27.442 |
| 25 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1657 | 25.112 |
| 26 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1717 | 23.542 |
| 27 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1777 | 24.052 |
| 28 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1837 | 18.762 |
| 29 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1897 | 19.132 |
| 30 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 1957 | 18.922 |
| 31 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2017 | 21.642 |
| 32 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2077 | 17.272 |
| 33 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2137 | 11.542 |
| 34 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2197 | 15.872 |
| 35 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2257 | 13.012 |
| 36 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2317 | 11.942 |
| 37 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2377 | 15.302 |
| 38 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2437 | 10.062 |
| 39 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2497 | 19.342 |
| 40 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2557 | 24.182 |
| 41 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2617 | 23.532 |
| 42 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2677 | 11.732 |
| 43 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2737 | 13.062 |
| 44 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2797 | 11.532 |
| 45 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2857 | 10.682 |
| 46 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2917 | 11.272 |
| 47 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 2977 | 11.192 |
| 48 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3037 | 11.512 |
| 49 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3097 | 11.842 |
| 50 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3157 | 10.412 |
| 51 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3217 | 10.252 |
| 52 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3277 | 11.112 |
| 53 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3337 | 10.162 |
| 54 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3397 | 12.062 |
| 55 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3457 | 9.992 |
| 56 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3517 | 10.112 |
| 57 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3577 | 11.462 |
| 58 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3637 | 10.622 |
| 59 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3697 | 10.872 |
| 60 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3757 | 10.422 |
| 61 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3817 | 11.102 |
| 62 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3877 | 11.132 |
| 63 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3937 | 10.942 |
| 64 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 3997 | 10.702 |
| 65 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4057 | 10.092 |
| 66 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4117 | 11.372 |
| 67 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4177 | 10.242 |
| 68 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4237 | 10.122 |
| 69 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4297 | 10.992 |
| 70 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4357 | 12.182 |
| 71 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4417 | 11.712 |
| 72 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4477 | 10.062 |
| 73 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4537 | 10.212 |
| 74 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4597 | 10.972 |
| 75 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4657 | 13.012 |
| 76 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4717 | 10.182 |
| 77 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4777 | 10.852 |
| 78 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4837 | 11.752 |
| 79 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4897 | 11.122 |
| 80 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 4957 | 11.752 |
| 81 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5017 | 12.242 |
| 82 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5077 | 11.412 |
| 83 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5137 | 10.172 |
| 84 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5197 | 10.442 |
| 85 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5257 | 11.502 |
| 86 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5317 | 11.712 |
| 87 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5377 | 10.602 |
| 88 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5437 | 11.942 |
| 89 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5497 | 10.332 |
| 90 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5557 | 10.892 |
| 91 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5617 | 11.642 |
| 92 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5677 | 10.342 |
| 93 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5737 | 10.962 |
| 94 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5797 | 10.432 |
| 95 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5857 | 12.102 |
| 96 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5917 | 10.612 |
| 97 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 5977 | 10.412 |
| 98 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6037 | 10.442 |
| 99 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6097 | 11.592 |
| 100 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6157 | 11.462 |
| 101 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6217 | 10.322 |
| 102 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6277 | 12.052 |
| 103 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6337 | 8.632 |
| 104 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6397 | 10.602 |
| 105 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6457 | 11.272 |
| 106 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6517 | 10.282 |
| 107 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6577 | 11.142 |
| 108 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6637 | 10.982 |
| 109 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6697 | 11.102 |
| 110 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6757 | 11.052 |
| 111 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6817 | 10.552 |
| 112 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6877 | 11.062 |
| 113 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6937 | 11.502 |
| 114 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 6997 | 10.982 |
| 115 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7057 | 10.642 |
| 116 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7117 | 9.232 |
| 117 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7177 | 10.812 |
| 118 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7237 | 11.252 |
| 119 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7297 | 15.902 |
| 120 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7357 | 17.702 |
| 121 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7417 | 11.932 |
| 122 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7477 | 19.822 |
| 123 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7537 | 18.892 |
| 124 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7597 | 24.932 |
| 125 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7657 | 25.422 |
| 126 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7717 | 27.742 |
| 127 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7777 | 28.802 |
| 128 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7837 | 29.022 |
| 129 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7897 | 31.052 |
| 130 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 7957 | 32.702 |
| 131 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8017 | 33.592 |
| 132 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8077 | 32.502 |
| 133 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8137 | 32.442 |
| 134 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8197 | 32.372 |
| 135 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8257 | 31.682 |
| 136 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8317 | 32.782 |
| 137 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8377 | 34.112 |
| 138 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8437 | 35.742 |
| 139 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8497 | 36.402 |
| 140 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8557 | 36.712 |
| 141 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8617 | 37.262 |
| 142 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8677 | 37.372 |
| 143 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8737 | 37.052 |
| 144 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8797 | 36.302 |
| 145 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8857 | 35.842 |
| 146 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8917 | 35.462 |
| 147 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 8977 | 34.652 |
| 148 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9037 | 34.042 |
| 149 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9097 | 33.922 |
| 150 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9157 | 33.312 |
| 151 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9217 | 32.942 |
| 152 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9277 | 32.542 |
| 153 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9337 | 31.602 |
| 154 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9397 | 31.412 |
| 155 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9457 | 31.152 |
| 156 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9517 | 31.112 |
| 157 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9577 | 30.812 |
| 158 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9637 | 30.942 |
| 159 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9697 | 30.002 |
| 160 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9757 | 29.762 |
| 161 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9817 | 29.092 |
| 162 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9877 | 29.192 |
| 163 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9937 | 29.062 |
| 164 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 9997 | 27.892 |
| 165 | 2021-12-11 10:01:33 | 10057 | 27.142 |
| 166 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 157 | 45.352 |
| 167 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 217 | 46.902 |
| 168 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 277 | 45.832 |
| 169 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 337 | 47.992 |
| 170 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 397 | 46.812 |
| 171 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 457 | 40.512 |
| 172 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 517 | 39.622 |
| 173 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 577 | 37.822 |
| 174 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 637 | 40.072 |
| 175 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 697 | 42.622 |
| 176 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 757 | 42.302 |
| 177 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 817 | 42.032 |
| 178 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 877 | 41.252 |
| 179 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 937 | 41.412 |
| 180 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 997 | 39.672 |
| 181 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1057 | 38.682 |
| 182 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1117 | 39.142 |
| 183 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1177 | 39.972 |
| 184 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1237 | 42.272 |
| 185 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1297 | 41.752 |
| 186 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1357 | 38.522 |
| 187 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1417 | 27.812 |
| 188 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1477 | 26.342 |
| 189 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1537 | 26.002 |
| 190 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1597 | 28.362 |
| 191 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1657 | 24.082 |
| 192 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1717 | 22.772 |
| 193 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1777 | 22.792 |
| 194 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1837 | 20.632 |
| 195 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1897 | 18.432 |
| 196 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 1957 | 18.802 |
| 197 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2017 | 20.982 |
| 198 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2077 | 21.282 |
| 199 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2137 | 17.682 |
| 200 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2197 | 10.772 |
| 201 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2257 | 10.822 |
| 202 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2317 | 20.962 |
| 203 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2377 | 11.142 |
| 204 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2437 | 10.672 |
| 205 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2497 | 11.752 |
| 206 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2557 | 24.672 |
| 207 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2617 | 27.992 |
| 208 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2677 | 24.152 |
| 209 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2737 | 11.072 |
| 210 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2797 | 11.182 |
| 211 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2857 | 13.152 |
| 212 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2917 | 12.122 |
| 213 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 2977 | 11.432 |
| 214 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3037 | 10.792 |
| 215 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3097 | 10.602 |
| 216 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3157 | 11.502 |
| 217 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3217 | 11.162 |
| 218 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3277 | 12.002 |
| 219 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3337 | 11.342 |
| 220 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3397 | 9.722 |
| 221 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3457 | 11.232 |
| 222 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3517 | 10.092 |
| 223 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3577 | 10.342 |
| 224 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3637 | 10.222 |
| 225 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3697 | 10.572 |
| 226 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3757 | 10.862 |
| 227 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3817 | 10.472 |
| 228 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3877 | 10.982 |
| 229 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3937 | 11.772 |
| 230 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 3997 | 11.092 |
| 231 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4057 | 12.442 |
| 232 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4117 | 11.582 |
| 233 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4177 | 11.292 |
| 234 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4237 | 9.692 |
| 235 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4297 | 15.542 |
| 236 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4357 | 10.642 |
| 237 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4417 | 11.282 |
| 238 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4477 | 11.402 |
| 239 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4537 | 10.532 |
| 240 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4597 | 10.922 |
| 241 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4657 | 11.052 |
| 242 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4717 | 10.952 |
| 243 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4777 | 10.282 |
| 244 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4837 | 11.712 |
| 245 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4897 | 11.052 |
| 246 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 4957 | 11.532 |
| 247 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5017 | 10.702 |
| 248 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5077 | 11.912 |
| 249 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5137 | 12.152 |
| 250 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5197 | 11.282 |
| 251 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5257 | 12.002 |
| 252 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5317 | 11.192 |
| 253 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5377 | 11.262 |
| 254 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5437 | 12.062 |
| 255 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5497 | 10.322 |
| 256 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5557 | 11.542 |
| 257 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5617 | 12.382 |
| 258 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5677 | 10.592 |
| 259 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5737 | 11.632 |
| 260 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5797 | 11.152 |
| 261 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5857 | 11.222 |
| 262 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5917 | 11.402 |
| 263 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 5977 | 9.652 |
| 264 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6037 | 10.452 |
| 265 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6097 | 11.382 |
| 266 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6157 | 12.152 |
| 267 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6217 | 10.012 |
| 268 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6277 | 9.872 |
| 269 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6337 | 10.122 |
| 270 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6397 | 10.672 |
| 271 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6457 | 11.402 |
| 272 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6517 | 11.612 |
| 273 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6577 | 10.262 |
| 274 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6637 | 10.882 |
| 275 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6697 | 11.212 |
| 276 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6757 | 10.192 |
| 277 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6817 | 11.972 |
| 278 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6877 | 10.882 |
| 279 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6937 | 11.112 |
| 280 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 6997 | 10.672 |
| 281 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7057 | 14.532 |
| 282 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7117 | 10.482 |
| 283 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7177 | 12.422 |
| 284 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7237 | 11.002 |
| 285 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7297 | 12.172 |
| 286 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7357 | 16.932 |
| 287 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7417 | 12.702 |
| 288 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7477 | 20.602 |
| 289 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7537 | 21.952 |
| 290 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7597 | 23.342 |
| 291 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7657 | 22.572 |
| 292 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7717 | 25.252 |
| 293 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7777 | 26.692 |
| 294 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7837 | 26.412 |
| 295 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7897 | 28.692 |
| 296 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 7957 | 30.072 |
| 297 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8017 | 30.172 |
| 298 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8077 | 29.992 |
| 299 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8137 | 30.012 |
| 300 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8197 | 30.872 |
| 301 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8257 | 30.572 |
| 302 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8317 | 30.492 |
| 303 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8377 | 30.562 |
| 304 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8437 | 30.682 |
| 305 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8497 | 31.532 |
| 306 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8557 | 31.472 |
| 307 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8617 | 32.112 |
| 308 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8677 | 32.352 |
| 309 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8737 | 31.802 |
| 310 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8797 | 31.472 |
| 311 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8857 | 31.072 |
| 312 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8917 | 30.092 |
| 313 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 8977 | 30.302 |
| 314 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9037 | 29.872 |
| 315 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9097 | 29.762 |
| 316 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9157 | 29.242 |
| 317 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9217 | 28.642 |
| 318 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9277 | 28.582 |
| 319 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9337 | 28.582 |
| 320 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9397 | 29.032 |
| 321 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9457 | 29.162 |
| 322 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9517 | 29.722 |
| 323 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9577 | 29.942 |
| 324 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9637 | 29.282 |
| 325 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9697 | 30.722 |
| 326 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9757 | 29.382 |
| 327 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9817 | 29.302 |
| 328 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9877 | 28.552 |
| 329 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9937 | 27.512 |
| 330 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 9997 | 27.712 |
| 331 | 2021-12-11 10:03:08 | 10057 | 27.552 |
| 332 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 157 | 45.472 |
| 333 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 217 | 46.362 |
| 334 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 277 | 45.102 |
| 335 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 337 | 47.742 |
| 336 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 397 | 47.322 |
| 337 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 457 | 41.622 |
| 338 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 517 | 41.952 |
| 339 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 577 | 40.762 |
| 340 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 637 | 40.142 |
| 341 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 697 | 37.602 |
| 342 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 757 | 40.202 |
| 343 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 817 | 41.592 |
| 344 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 877 | 41.782 |
| 345 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 937 | 42.002 |
| 346 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 997 | 42.342 |
| 347 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1057 | 45.372 |
| 348 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1117 | 46.302 |
| 349 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1177 | 46.022 |
| 350 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1237 | 37.462 |
| 351 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1297 | 26.652 |
| 352 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1357 | 27.752 |
| 353 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1417 | 26.192 |
| 354 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1477 | 25.552 |
| 355 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1537 | 25.712 |
| 356 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1597 | 27.172 |
| 357 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1657 | 24.002 |
| 358 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1717 | 22.482 |
| 359 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1777 | 21.982 |
| 360 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1837 | 19.602 |
| 361 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1897 | 21.082 |
| 362 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 1957 | 23.502 |
| 363 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2017 | 22.522 |
| 364 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2077 | 11.052 |
| 365 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2137 | 12.032 |
| 366 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2197 | 18.372 |
| 367 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2257 | 17.742 |
| 368 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2317 | 11.242 |
| 369 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2377 | 10.952 |
| 370 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2437 | 12.292 |
| 371 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2497 | 17.902 |
| 372 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2557 | 19.362 |
| 373 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2617 | 18.712 |
| 374 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2677 | 23.892 |
| 375 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2737 | 10.312 |
| 376 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2797 | 10.622 |
| 377 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2857 | 10.522 |
| 378 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2917 | 10.682 |
| 379 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 2977 | 9.802 |
| 380 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3037 | 10.682 |
| 381 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3097 | 11.302 |
| 382 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3157 | 11.562 |
| 383 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3217 | 10.282 |
| 384 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3277 | 10.972 |
| 385 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3337 | 11.492 |
| 386 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3397 | 9.882 |
| 387 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3457 | 11.062 |
| 388 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3517 | 9.642 |
| 389 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3577 | 10.722 |
| 390 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3637 | 10.002 |
| 391 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3697 | 10.502 |
| 392 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3757 | 9.622 |
| 393 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3817 | 11.362 |
| 394 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3877 | 11.152 |
| 395 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3937 | 10.482 |
| 396 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 3997 | 10.102 |
| 397 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4057 | 10.082 |
| 398 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4117 | 11.562 |
| 399 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4177 | 9.542 |
| 400 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4237 | 10.422 |
| 401 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4297 | 9.422 |
| 402 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4357 | 10.972 |
| 403 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4417 | 12.552 |
| 404 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4477 | 10.292 |
| 405 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4537 | 10.202 |
| 406 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4597 | 10.632 |
| 407 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4657 | 10.062 |
| 408 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4717 | 10.402 |
| 409 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4777 | 11.702 |
| 410 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4837 | 11.332 |
| 411 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4897 | 12.972 |
| 412 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 4957 | 11.502 |
| 413 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5017 | 11.722 |
| 414 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5077 | 11.092 |
| 415 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5137 | 10.722 |
| 416 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5197 | 11.872 |
| 417 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5257 | 10.682 |
| 418 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5317 | 10.422 |
| 419 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5377 | 11.962 |
| 420 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5437 | 11.412 |
| 421 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5497 | 10.872 |
| 422 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5557 | 11.832 |
| 423 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5617 | 11.042 |
| 424 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5677 | 11.342 |
| 425 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5737 | 11.572 |
| 426 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5797 | 10.532 |
| 427 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5857 | 10.942 |
| 428 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5917 | 12.642 |
| 429 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 5977 | 11.332 |
| 430 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6037 | 10.062 |
| 431 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6097 | 11.162 |
| 432 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6157 | 11.752 |
| 433 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6217 | 10.612 |
| 434 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6277 | 11.412 |
| 435 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6337 | 10.292 |
| 436 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6397 | 10.942 |
| 437 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6457 | 9.892 |
| 438 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6517 | 10.872 |
| 439 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6577 | 9.552 |
| 440 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6637 | 10.012 |
| 441 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6697 | 10.112 |
| 442 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6757 | 9.872 |
| 443 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6817 | 10.282 |
| 444 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6877 | 11.422 |
| 445 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6937 | 10.452 |
| 446 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 6997 | 11.562 |
| 447 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7057 | 11.542 |
| 448 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7117 | 10.892 |
| 449 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7177 | 11.482 |
| 450 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7237 | 20.802 |
| 451 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7297 | 12.332 |
| 452 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7357 | 24.812 |
| 453 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7417 | 23.622 |
| 454 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7477 | 26.882 |
| 455 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7537 | 26.412 |
| 456 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7597 | 25.372 |
| 457 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7657 | 24.662 |
| 458 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7717 | 17.512 |
| 459 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7777 | 25.002 |
| 460 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7837 | 19.192 |
| 461 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7897 | 23.832 |
| 462 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 7957 | 23.842 |
| 463 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8017 | 25.172 |
| 464 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8077 | 25.682 |
| 465 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8137 | 24.932 |
| 466 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8197 | 25.782 |
| 467 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8257 | 27.542 |
| 468 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8317 | 29.262 |
| 469 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8377 | 29.552 |
| 470 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8437 | 30.262 |
| 471 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8497 | 30.752 |
| 472 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8557 | 30.482 |
| 473 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8617 | 30.752 |
| 474 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8677 | 31.312 |
| 475 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8737 | 30.272 |
| 476 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8797 | 30.882 |
| 477 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8857 | 30.402 |
| 478 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8917 | 29.732 |
| 479 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 8977 | 29.952 |
| 480 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9037 | 29.512 |
| 481 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9097 | 30.222 |
| 482 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9157 | 30.232 |
| 483 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9217 | 30.992 |
| 484 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9277 | 31.052 |
| 485 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9337 | 31.562 |
| 486 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9397 | 31.332 |
| 487 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9457 | 31.642 |
| 488 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9517 | 31.092 |
| 489 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9577 | 31.592 |
| 490 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9637 | 31.012 |
| 491 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9697 | 31.422 |
| 492 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9757 | 30.852 |
| 493 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9817 | 30.922 |
| 494 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9877 | 30.592 |
| 495 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9937 | 29.262 |
| 496 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 9997 | 28.402 |
| 497 | 2021-12-11 10:04:44 | 10057 | 28.792 |
| 498 | 2021-12-11 10:06:19 | 157 | 46.032 |
| 499 | 2021-12-11 10:06:19 | 217 | 48.312 |

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only rows with range equal to 217, you can just filter dataframe by that field.

```
df[df["range(m)"] == 217]
```

This is the output:

```
2021-12-11 10:01:33    217     46.612
2021-12-11 10:03:08    217     46.902
2021-12-11 10:04:44    217     46.362
2021-12-11 10:06:19    217     48.312
```